# Trouble getting a responce from my script

Tags: jquery, html, audio, jplayer

i use jplayer as an audio player in my site...Most of the commands are **HTML5 standard**.

I am trying to get the **$.jPlayer.event.progress** event to fire so that i can record its value and if it is >0 i know the audio stream is playing on the users machine..

Trouble is i cant get a result from it, and my jquery is ... well...  not so advanced :)

I cant really do a fiddle to show because of my lack of testing knowledge, all i can say is that the stream works fine.

I am expecting to see results between "0 and 10" (0 meaning not streaming) (1-10 meaning the ammount of data that has been buffered in seconds)

**THE HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/testsite/scripts/player.js"></script>



</head>

<body>

<p id="message"></p>

<br>


<div id="liveStream"></div>
<button onclick="playPause()">PLAY or PAUSE</button>
<button onclick="changeVolume('+')">Volume Up</button>
<button onclick="changeVolume('-')">Volume Down</button>
<button onclick="playStatus()">Play Status</button>


</body>
</html>
</body>

</html>
```

**THE SCRIPT:**

It is the **playstatus** function that i am trying to return results from, you can see im trying to log everything in the function due to my lack of understanding

```
function playStatus(){
     $("#liveStream").bind($.jPlayer.event.progress, function (event) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(playStatus);
        console.log(liveStream);
    });
}

//Initiate JPLAYER 

$(document).ready(function(){

    var stream = {
        mp3: "http://streaming.radionomy.com/ABC-Jazz"

    },
    ready = false;

    $("#liveStream").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            ready = true;
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream);
        },
        pause: function() {
            $(this).jPlayer("clearMedia");
        },
        error: function(event) {
            if(ready && event.jPlayer.error.type === $.jPlayer.error.URL_NOT_SET) {
                // Setup the media stream again and play it.
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream).jPlayer("play");
            }
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3",
        preload: "none",
        wmode: "window",
        keyEnabled: true
    });


});
```

Here is a link to JPlayers DEV list, I am trying to initiate and log **$.jPlayer.event.progress**

[JPLAYER EVENTS](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/)

Thanks for taking the time to read through!

Comment: This line bugs me "<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>"

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is check if the player is playing or not, just use a basic hack like this to see if the play button is hidden or not (if it is hidden, this means it's playing because the pause button is visible instead).

```
if( $('.jp-play').is(':hidden') ) { 
    // it's playing 
} else {
    // it's not playing
}
```

Comment: i am not using their in build css, i need to make scripts for each event so that i can access them in adobe edge later on

Comment: Something like this might help

    `if($("#liveStream").jPlayer("getData","diag.isPlaying") == true){ 

//Is Playing   

}`

Comment: Thanks but its going away from what i am trying to achieve